# Android Bluetooth using GraphView and Arduino

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, arduino, signal-processing

I currently have a realtime graph (Android GraphView) running smoothly from my arduino's analog sensor to a bluetooth module and then being streamed on the Android with the following code. I was wondering if someone can point me in the right direction to create a function that receives the double s returned in this function and averages every 5 values to return it. The stream is sending a new double every 20 miliseconds from the arduino. I tried adding a loop with counter to store every 5 values in an array and divide the sum by 5, but it's not repeating in realtime.

```
public static double read() throws IOException
 {
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      dataInStream = new DataInputStream(mmInStream);
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataInStream);
      double s = scanner.nextDouble();
      }
      return s;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

try to add synchronized before double or may be before static. like this
public static synchronized  double read() throws IOException...
hope it will work for you